# Correct GraphicsContext When Using UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext

Tags: iphone, ios, cocoa-touch, core-graphics, quartz-graphics

I have the following method where I'm trying to do some drawing into an image:

```
- (UIImage*) renderImage
{
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(self.size, NO, 0);
    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
    //drawing code

    UIImage *image = [UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext() retain];
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();  
    return [image autorelease];    
}
```

When I run this code I noticed that I'm getting hit much harder than I did when I was simply drawing this code in `drawRect` of a `UIView`. Am I drawing into the wrong graphics context here (ie `CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();`)? Or is `UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext` just that much more expensive than drawing in `drawRect`?

Comment: Good question, I'd say it allocates more memory, since you now draw onto the view *plus* get a copy of the image as well.

Comment: Something just does not seem right, I'm loading a tableview of images and it's about 2-3 times slower.

Comment: I found this in the docs for UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext: "The current graphics context is nil by default. Prior to calling its drawRect: method, view objects push a valid context onto the stack, making it current. If you are not using a UIView object to do your drawing, however, you must push a valid context onto the stack manually using the UIGraphicsPushContext function."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main difference is that the context that you create requires an offscreen rendering, it isn't the same context created in -drawRect. So you are adding an additional memory to the heap that stays until you will release the image.