# Draw lines with Glow effect smoothly in iPad

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad

I have integrated drawing a line in my application. I have not used OpenGl or any other similar framework. Now I want to give a glow effect to these lines. Any idea how to do that?
Thanks in advance..

Comment: Do you have an example of what you want it to look like?

Comment: see my answer from this que.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13173933/correct-graphicscontext-when-using-uigraphicsgetimagefromcurrentimagecontext